# Create multi-binding with a customized markup extension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I am working on a feature that requires me to use a customized Markup extension. The markup extension is developed by others. Looking at the markup extension class it looks like data binding to me (correct me if I am wrong please). Here is the sketch of the customized mark up extension:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingExpression))]
public class Lookup : MarkupExtension
{
    private string name;
    public Lookup(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {   
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        /*some code that involves this.name*/
        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);   
    }
}
```

Then I could use this customized markup extension in my xaml code like this:

```
<MyControl MyProperty={MyNamespace:Lookup propertyName}/>
```

And it will call LookUp class and pass in `propertyName` and return a value.

My question is that I would like to use this customized markup extension to bind to multiple values; essentially perform something like multi-binding. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var binding = new MultiBinding();
            binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding(pathOfWhatEverOne));
            binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding(pathOfWhatEverTwo));
            ...
            /*some code that involves this.name*/
            return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
```

Just switch the `Binding` to `MultiBinding` and add some Sub-Bindings